# Dont get access token

Tags: api, postman, linkedin-api

I am using Oauth2 to get the access token, i can get the code but when I am using postman to get the access token i get an status 403.

this is the url that i am using:

```
https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/V2/accesstoken?grant_type=authorization_code&code=AQSSeTJlPER2UXROrlcxnZu1233VFqSGpnbb3LbySelnmayljjpasMtsCGJkPOD-tXGl4U_P-7q-OUxZl9cIvwo1niVT4v9UxfkBk-i0b4ZhY_2rKugw-ZXCPbQrf9qlfj9TX2eraJzfykUT78I7M6HRB0NMz5iqlnOmPvE5Yf6S486OTomn5xI-E2fk-FA&client_id=86k52xk4123dza&client_secret=kaouvpg1212iJyrw&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2F/www.test.co%2
```

Response:

`<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Unauthorized</title>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="data:image/png;base64,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">
        <style>
            html, body, pre {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                font-family: Monaco, 'Lucida Console', monospace;
                background: #ECECEC;
            }
            h1 {
                margin: 0;
                background: #333;
                padding: 20px 45px;
                color: #fff;
                text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
                border-bottom: 1px solid #111;
                font-size: 28px;
            }`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are making a GET request which results in the parameters being sent as query-string parameters, according to step 3 here: https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/oauth2

They expect you to make a POST request which would cause the parameters to be sent via form parameters.

If you are using postman click the GET icon next to your URL and change it to POST.

====EDIT=====

You should remove your client_id and client_secret from the code sample. This is very insecure and can allow someone to make requests to LinkedIn using your account.